# AppDynamics Business Transactions by url parameter values

Tags: appdynamics

I have a REST service that accesses a Redis database to retrieve a large data object. To populate all of the elements of the data object requires many calls to the database.
The REST service is using AppD to monitor the application.
All of the calls contain the planID in the url.
I would like to be able to count all of the calls per planID to determine how many calls to the database are needed for each planID to populate the data object.
Below is a picture of the business transactions that show the data

[image]

The first 3 transactions use the same planID. I would like to create a dashboard that counts the number of calls per planID.
Is there a way in the dashboard of AppDynamics to do this?

Comment: Do you have Transaction Analytics for this Application?

Comment: I'm not sure....is that a specific module that needs to be installed?  I have an 'Analytics' tab and tabs for business transactions but I don't see any tab or page for Transaction Analytics?

Comment: It needs to be licensed to work with additional agent setup, data coming from APM Business Transactions comes under "Transaction Analytics" (all the different forms of Analytics source data are used under the "Analytics tab referenced). See https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/analytics

Comment: If you do not have Transaction Analytics available. Are you able to specify a location in your instrumented application code where the planID is known to be used? (i.e. a class / method / parameter combination or a HTTP header value)

Comment: I found the Transaction Analytics in the AppDynamics (Analytics/Configuration).  There are only 3 applications listed.  Not the one I need.
The screenshot in the original post shows the business transactions I want to count based on the planID.  Is there a way to count these transactions based on planID in a dashboard?

Comment: Are you able to specify a location in your instrumented application code where the planID is known to be used? (i.e. a class / method / parameter combination or a HTTP header value)

Comment: There probably is.  But am not on the development team.  I was looking at the business transaction page (shown above) on AppD and saw the endpoint (api/v1/plans/{planUUID}/... and URL instances with the planUUID populated for each URL call and thought there might be a way to count thoses calls based on plannUUID.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a direct way to do what you are asking with AppDynamics using Business Transaction APM data (as above) alone. However there are two indirect ways using additional features.

**Option 1 - Use Transaction Analytics**

Using Business Transactions data in Analytics you are able to do advanced (SQL like) searching.

Setup an HTTP Data Collector to capture the URL and send this to Analytics - see https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/application-monitoring/configure-instrumentation/data-collectors

This will then give a value for segments.httpData.url for each Transactions record which can be used in ADQL queries to for example group by a segment of the URL. ADQL reference is here https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/22.3/en/analytics/adql-reference

See requirements for Transaction Analytics here: https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/analytics

**Option 2 - Use API's to Export**

Using the Metric & Snapshot API (see https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/extend-appdynamics/appdynamics-apis/metric-and-snapshot-api) you could export Transaction data and then use any tooling to perform analysis

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question well you are trying to ultimately count each plan. I think that I could create a custom rule (in Transaction Detection) to split your business transactions on the 4th segment. That new rule will create BT's for each plan, and you can create dashboard from that.

Good luck.

Comment: This could work if only a few plans, but note that Applications have a 200 BT limit so depends on the number of plans here.